# Error-500 running vNext MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to run some vNext MVC test application(such as the default sample application available for vNext in vs14) whenever I run the application it got build successfully but in browser I got 500 error (did not make any code change). Then I tried through command prompt by `k web` command it just show `started` but when I navigate the url I cannot see the page loaded (using IE 11 - as default and Firefox nightly). I also tried to run non vNext MVC application but they worked perfectly.

Another problem is whenever I build an application say vNext console application there is no "bin" folder got created and it does not compile for targeted frameworks and no "nuget" packages. But when I run `kpm build` it compiles for all targeted frameworks and does create "bin" folder. In visual studio 14 ctp the "active target framework" is .NET Framework 4.5 and there is no other option except core framework 4.5

Please do help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Currently I'm able to build and run MVC 6 apps. The solution is such as before every time I build a new MVC 6 app I got to re-download KVM by the command provided in ASPNET/Home in git. Well, this is not supposed to be the way of build-run MVC 6. Yet I'm not sure about the root of the problem.